friend template function results in Undefined symbols bug error
Context:
The program is supposed to have a template for a single linked list where you can find info through the key. I meant to implement a split function that would take in one source sequence, start splitting it at “start” index, then send “step1” amount of items to result1, then “step2” amount of items to result2, and so on until there runs out of items in source to complete the next step amount, then the rest of items in source are just given to the current sequence.
I don't understand why I get this bug:
ld: Undefined symbols:
split(Sequence<char, int> const&, int, Sequence<char, int>&, int, int, Sequence<char, int>&, int, int), referenced from:
_main in main-123c17.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

For this code:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>  
#include <ctime>    
using namespace std;

template <typename Key, typename Info>
// a template for a single linked list in which you may find an element's info with a key (keys are not unique)(will implement find later)
class Sequence {
private:
    struct Node {
        Key key;
        Info info;
        Node* next;
        Node(Key k, Info i) : key(k), info(i), next(nullptr) {}
    }; 
    Node* head;
    int length;

public:
    Sequence() : head(nullptr), length(0) {}

    void push(Key k, Info i) {
        // adds a node to the end of the sequence
        Node* newNode = new Node(k, i);
        if ( !head) {
            head = newNode;
        } else {
            Node* temp = head;
            while (temp->next) {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp->next = newNode;
        }
        length++;
    }

    //copy constructor
    Sequence(const Sequence<Key, Info>& other) : head(nullptr), length(0) {
        Node* current = other.head;
        while (current) {
            push(current->key, current->info);
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

    //destructor
    ~Sequence() {
        while (head) {
            Node* temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
        }
    }

    //printing all info from a sequence
    void print(){
        Node* current = head;
        while (current) {
            cout << "(" << current->info << ") -> ";
            current = current->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    friend void split(const Sequence<Key, Info>& source, int start,
              Sequence<Key, Info>& result1, int step1, int length1,
              Sequence<Key, Info>& result2, int step2, int length2);
};


template <typename Key, typename Info>
void split(const Sequence<Key, Info>& source, int start,
           Sequence<Key, Info>& result1, int step1, int length1,
           Sequence<Key, Info>& result2, int step2, int length2) {

    typename Sequence<Key, Info>::Node* current = source.head;
    int index = 0;

    while (index < start) {
        current = current->next;
        index++;
    }

    bool toResult1 = true; 
    while (current &&(length1 > 0 || length2 > 0)){
        int steps = toResult1 ? step1 : step2;
        int& currentLength = toResult1 ? length1 : length2;
        int movingLength;

        Sequence<Key, Info>& targetSequence = toResult1 ? result1 : result2;
        int targetLength = toResult1 ? length1 : length2;

        for (int i = 0; i < steps && current && currentLength > 0; i++) {
            targetSequence.push(current->key, current->info);
            current = current->next;
            currentLength--;
            targetLength++;
        }
        if (targetLength + steps <= currentLength ){
            toResult1 = !toResult1; //once the steps are done, move onto the next res list
        }else {
            for (int i = 0; i <currentLength; i++) {
            targetSequence.push(current->key, current->info);
            current = current->next;
            currentLength--;
            }
        }
    }
}


int main(){
    
    Sequence<char, int> source;
    Sequence<char, int> result1;
    Sequence<char, int> result2;

    source.push('A', 1);
    source.push('B', 2);
    source.push('C', 3);
    source.push('D', 4);
    source.push('E', 5);
    source.push('F', 6);
    source.push('G', 7);
    source.push('H', 8);
    
    cout << "Source:";
    source.print();

    split(source, 2, result1, 2, 3, result2, 1, 3);

    cout << "Result 1:";
    result1.print();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Result 2:";
    result2.print();
    cout << endl;

    return 0;

}

split is a friend of the class, and there is a main function. I don't know what to fix since this is all I'm getting. Is it something simple I'm overlooking or a logical flaw or smt else..?

You are not declaring your friend function correctly.
Before the class definition, you need to do the following forward declarations:
template <typename Key, typename Info> class Sequence;

template <typename Key, typename Info>
void split(const Sequence<Key, Info>& source, int start,
    Sequence<Key, Info>& result1, int step1, int length1,
    Sequence<Key, Info>& result2, int step2, int length2);

Then, the friend function must be declared with the template parameters, otherwise the compiler will believe you intend to use a split non-template function, which obviously does not exist.
You can do it by referencing the template type parameters:
friend void split<Key, Info>(const Sequence<Key, Info>& source, int start,
    Sequence<Key, Info>& result1, int step1, int length1,
    Sequence<Key, Info>& result2, int step2, int length2);

Or you can omit them and use the full template specialization:
friend void split<>(const Sequence<Key, Info>& source, int start,
    Sequence<Key, Info>& result1, int step1, int length1,
    Sequence<Key, Info>& result2, int step2, int length2);


The template arguments in the friend declaration are optional because they can be deduced.
